# I got whitelabel error page instead of eureka dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm following a tutorial about Eureka to start up a sample eureka server ,I followed exactly the same steps but i get a whitelabel insteed of eureka dashbord, I will share with you all the configuration that I made

the POM.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com..discovery.service</groupId>
<artifactId>descoveryservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>descoveryservice</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

application.properties :

```
server.port=8010
spring.application.name=discoveryservice
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8010/eureka
```

and the finally the console :

```
    2020-05-07 16:15:59.358  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain annotation attribute value for public abstract java.lang.Class[] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass.value()
2020-05-07 16:15:59.679  INFO 21060 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97f8ff4f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2020-05-07 16:16:01.722  INFO 21060 --- [           main] c.d.s.d.DescoveryserviceApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-07 16:16:02.829  WARN 21060 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-05-07 16:16:03.242  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=889ab658-056e-3973-ba9c-f9fdd0f82c43
2020-05-07 16:16:03.378  INFO 21060 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97f8ff4f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-07 16:16:04.447  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8010 (http)
2020-05-07 16:16:04.491  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-07 16:16:04.491  INFO 21060 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2020-05-07 16:16:04.509  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.6/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.6/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\novatim\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\novatim\Desktop\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin;;C:\Users\novatim\Desktop\eclipse-jee-2019-12-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
2020-05-07 16:16:04.768  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-07 16:16:04.768  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2996 ms
2020-05-07 16:16:04.935  WARN 21060 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-05-07 16:16:04.936  INFO 21060 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-05-07 16:16:04.962  INFO 21060 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@13ed066e
2020-05-07 16:16:06.652  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2020-05-07 16:16:08.337  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2020-05-07 16:16:08.963  WARN 21060 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-05-07 16:16:08.964  INFO 21060 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-05-07 16:16:09.222  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-07 16:16:10.021  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-05-07 16:16:10.174  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2020-05-07 16:16:10.226  INFO 21060 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2020-05-07 16:16:10.229  INFO 21060 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2020-05-07 16:16:10.243  INFO 21060 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1588860970242 with initial instances count: 0
2020-05-07 16:16:10.250  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application discoveryservice with eureka with status UP
2020-05-07 16:16:10.326  INFO 21060 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8010 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-07 16:16:10.333  INFO 21060 --- [           main] c.d.s.d.DescoveryserviceApplication      : Started DescoveryserviceApplication in 13.391 seconds (JVM running for 14.094)
2020-05-07 16:16:17.202  INFO 21060 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-07 16:16:17.204  INFO 21060 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-07 16:16:17.223  INFO 21060 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 19 ms
```

I do not know where the problem is it has been several hours that I am looking for a solution, if you have ideas do not hesitate to share them, 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't add @EnableEurekaServer annotation to your main app
It should be like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {
…
}
```

Comment: Thank You that was it !